# Problems using a Konica Minolta Bizhub 161 with windows 7 (64-bit)

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, printer

I have just had to upgrade my PC and have migrated from Vista (32-bit) to Windows 7(64-bit). I was not able to install or find any drivers for my konica minolta printer/scanner (bizhub 161) and have now been informed by their customer service department that there are no compatible drivers available for my windows 7 64-bit OS. They did mention that there may be some generic pcl drivers available but could not officially recommend them since they would not have been developed by themselves. Could anyone suggest where I could find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate you can try out "[XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx)".

Comment: tks but unfortunately I've got windows 7 home premium installed